# Google Script, how can I copy a row from Sheet1 to Sheet2 instead of just one cell by using regex?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Extremely in-experienced coder here, I have been working on a regex function that searches for keywords in transcripts, then populates a spreadsheet with a transcript if the keywords are found. However, I have only worked out how to populate the sheet with only the one cell, containing the transcript, whereas I want to populate the entire row in which has the transcript cell as well as other cells containing urls, date and times, etc.

Here is my code:

```
function regexwithsheetpop() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var historySheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');  
var resultsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Results');
var totalRowsWithData = historySheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
var data = historySheet.getRange(1, 2, totalRowsWithData).getValues(); 
var regexp = /\W*(identity)\W*\s+(\w+\s+){0,5}(verification)|(verification)\s+(\w+\s+){0,5}(identity)/i;
var result = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
     var row = data[i];
     var column = row[0];
     if (regexp.exec(column) !== null) {
        result.push(row); }}
if (result.length > 0) {
    var resultsSheetDataRows = resultsSheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
    resultsSheetDataRows = resultsSheetDataRows === 1 ? resultsSheetDataRows : resultsSheetDataRows + 1; 
    var resultsSheetRange = resultsSheet.getRange(resultsSheetDataRows, 1, result.length);
  resultsSheetRange.setValues(result);}}
```

So I search Column B in "Sheet1", which contains all the transcripts, for keywords. And if a keyword is found, the regex function populates the "Results" sheet with the transcripts. I would like it if the regex function populates the "Results" sheet with Column A, B and C of "Sheet1" if there is a keyword found in Column B of "Sheet1".

Again, very in-experienced coder here so any simplified or dumb-down feedback would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Here is a simplification: Google App Script is not recommended until you have an impossible task or are sure it will result in a noticeable performance increase (extremely rare and almost always the opposite). The answer to this question with the current details provided is delete that App Script and use formulas. If you provide a sample sheet with sample data and desired sample output link we can give you a very specific solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! You're most of the way there. To pull in the additional columns from "sheet1", you simply need to include an extra argument in `getRange()` to get all 3 columns (A, B, C):

```
var data = historySheet.getRange(1, 1, totalRowsWithData, 3).getValues()
```

See [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).

Then tweak your for-loop to match the regex on column B and push the entire `row` array onto `results` if a match is found.

More about multi-dimensional range outputs here: [How do I write data to a single range in Google Apps Script?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106503/how-do-i-write-data-to-a-single-range-in-google-apps-script)

And finally, add another argument for the number of columns for `resultsSheetRange`.

```
function regexwithsheetpop() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var historySheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1')
    var resultsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Results')

    var totalRowsWithData = historySheet.getDataRange().getNumRows()
    var data = historySheet.getRange(1, 1, totalRowsWithData, 3).getValues()
    var regexp = /\W*(identity)\W*\s+(\w+\s+){0,5}(verification)|(verification)\s+(\w+\s+){0,5}(identity)/i
    var result = []

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
        var row = data[i]
        var column = row[1]
        if (regexp.exec(column) !== null) {
            result.push(row)
        }
    }

    if (result.length > 0) {
        var resultsSheetDataRows = resultsSheet.getDataRange().getNumRows()
        resultsSheetDataRows =
            resultsSheetDataRows === 1
                ? resultsSheetDataRows
                : resultsSheetDataRows + 1
        var resultsSheetRange = resultsSheet.getRange(
            resultsSheetDataRows,
            1,
            result.length,
            3
        )
        resultsSheetRange.setValues(result)
    }
}
```